# StreamWriter sends two new line in SSH Terminal

Tags: vb.net, newline, streamwriter

I am having a problem on `StreamWriter`.

I create a SSHCOM terminal, then use the `StreamWriter` to Write the command.

The command successfully write into the terminal, but my problem is that the `WriteLine` is sending two newlines, the second [New Line] causing the command to terminate after executing.

Comment: code please? are you appending a newline to the command?

Comment: WriteLine() will most likely use CrLf for the new line, where your ssh server most likely expects just expects LF

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above - we need some code...

If you use WriteLine method, this is why you have an extra newline , so do not append your own newline character...

Comment: Writer.WriteLine("cd /root/.setup/audio && amixer -c 1 set PCM 30% && mplayer " & loadedMusicSpeaker & " -ao alsa:device=hw=1.0")

Comment: are you sure its double newline ? maybe you mean cr+lf ? chr(13)+chr(10) ?